# How do I save greater number in variable in Bash shell script?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a bash shell app that count rx and tx packets. These packets every second has change then save it inside SUM variable. My goal is to save greater number in new variable. How can I do that?

```
SUM=$(expr $TKBPS + $RKBPS)

now=$(( $SUM))

if [ $now -gt $SUM ] ; then
    max=$(( $now ))
fi

  
echo "SUM is: $SUM"
echo "MAX is: $max"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bug in your code is: `if [ $now -gt $max ]` (max, not SUM).

You can write it better like this:

```
sum=$((TKBPS+RKBPS))

max=$((sum>max?sum:max))
# ((sum>max)) && max=$sum # or like this

echo "sum is $sum"
echo "max is $max"
```

Answer (score 0):

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# Example of a previously calculated SUM that gives MAX number 5
max=5

SUM=$(($A + $B))

# Update max only if new sum is greater than it
[ $SUM -gt $max ] && max=$SUM

echo $max
```

Example:

```
$ A=5 B=9 bash program
14

$ A=1 B=1 bash program
5
```

Comment: `SUM=$(expr $TKBPS + $RKBPS)` This variable cannot change. It gets results from rx and tx packets from internet.  So your program cannot work.

Comment: Your input source is not clear, is `SUM` in a while loop or how its value will change again after assignment ?

Comment: Bash code should generally not need or want to use `expr`; the shell has built-in facilities which supersede this legacy tool for the original Bourne shell.

Comment: The only use for `expr` in a POSIX shell is for regular expression matching.